# php cron job failing but works manually

Tags: php, cron

I'm having a strange issue.  I can't post the code here because i have an NDA.

If I go to `example.com/cron/parse_inventory.php` in the browser the scripts run perfectly fine, with no errors.

Now when it runs via cron - it throws an error saying cannot find my csv file that is getting parsed.

`curl -s "example.com/cron/parse_inventory.php"`

I'm not sure what I can check to validate the issue. Like I said when I run the script in the browser the script runs perfectly.  And Yes, the file does in fact exist.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Change the data that is sensitive and post it here. My guess is that your path is relative and your server call is at the wrong location.

Comment: cant debug code we cant see.

Comment: Personally, I usually use wget when I want to hit a web URL from cron

Comment: why does it have to be hit from a web interface? all my cronjob php is CLI

Comment: post the path of your csv....

Comment: Why post the question if you know you'll never meet the requirements of a Minimum Example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue with the cron script was the includes that were being added were using relative paths.  I switched them to fixed paths and all worked well.  It was just a little strange because when you call it in the browser it works fine, it was being called as a URL inside the cron job so it should have worked the same, but apparently not.